# Jquery fadeIn Issue (Page Issue)

Tags: jquery, fadein

So I want to create a simple fading in animation for the main page on my website. However the code I have used in the Javascript file doesn't seem to allow it to fade in. I have literally tried everything so I'm hoping someone can help me with this.

I have linked my own Javascript file and the Jquery file.

This is the div I want to fadeIn when the page loads.

```
<div id="flat6logo"> 
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript code for the fading of the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flat6logo").hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem, I know it is something stupid which I have missed out. I have tried literally everything to fix the problem including using the display:none code which also doesn't work.

Comment: Should work! You're sure the links to the JS files are correct.

Comment: It works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LkgwC/

Comment: Your code works if you style it to `display:none` and remove `.hide()`
http://jsfiddle.net/LkgwC/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `hide` kills the `fadein`

I think this should solve your problem, the `fadein` should work upon the hide completing it's task

```
 $("#flat6logo").hide(function(){fadeIn('slow')});
```

Answer (score -2):

You cant use hide and fadeIn together. Try to use this.

```
$(function(){
    $('#flat6logo').hide('slow');
})
```

Comment: The OP asked for fading in and not fading out.

Comment: What?! http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete or see the example on doc page.

Comment: To those comments saying it works, I have just tried again and it still doesn't work, any suggestions? I have a feeling it has something to do with the actual HTML file or Javascript file.

Comment: Also I have parented the different Javascript files using 
<link href="#" type="javascript"/>

Comment: I was wrong about hide() not accepting arguments. However, this solution doesn't show the element like the original code.